# Unable to print man pages from man -command

Tags: printing

I want to get man pages to stout.
However, I have not managed a way to do that.

**Pseudo-code about what I am trying to achieve**

```
man man | lpr
```

**How can you print a manual,** such that you see first how many pages is going to be printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
man -Tps man | lpr
```

This tells man to format the output as a postscript file which can be piped directly to a printer. See the man page for further -T (troff) formatting options.

To preview the output pipe it to a file and view it with gv or okular.

```
man -Tps man > manual.ps
gv manual.ps
```

Comment: Do you know how you can get the number of pages before you print the manual?

Comment: See my edits above, I can't think of a way to count the pages from the command line.

Comment: @sekenre: I get the following error message: http://dpaste.com/60058/

Comment: It seems that OS/X's man does not have the option T.

Comment: @Masi: Try using man -t python | lpr Your version has that option.

Comment: @sekenre: Thank you very much! --- The command works by the use of Python.

Answer (score 1):

man ls | col -b | lpr -P my_printer

This prints the man page for "ls" formats it using "col" and then prints on the printer named "my_printer"

The formatting isn't required, but gets rid of special characters making it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of man (at least my version on openSuSE 11 :) ) automatically detect if output is a terminal or a pipe. If you want non-formatted man pages to stdout, try:

```
man man | cat
```

For manpages going to the printer, I like:

```
man man | a2ps --stdin='man(1)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to # of pages question above(need 50 rep to add comments):

```
man ls | wc -l | awk '{ print $1/60 }'
```

The default # of lines per page is 60, so if you aren't changing that, then just divide by 60 and round up.  I forget how to make awk treat FP as INT so that it rounds for you.

Comment: @Josh: What is FP?

Comment: sorry for the late response. FP = floating point; INT = integer.  It would be useful to have it translated into an INT if you were planning on using the output for another automated purpose(ie - piping a one liner or in a script).